# Cannot connect from Windows 10 Hyper-V Manager to another Windows 10 Hyper-V instance

Tags: windows, hyper-v, windows-10

I got a Windows 10 Workstation at home where I installed Hyper-V and run a Windows 10 VM inside it. Then I got a Notebook where Windows 10 is installed and I want to connect and administrate the Workstations Hyper-V VMs, so I installed Hyper-V Manager on my Laptop. When I now try to connect to the Workstation I got an error "An error occurred while attempting to connect to server. Check that the Virtual Machine Management service is running and that you are authorized to connect to the server".

What does than mean? Both - Workstation and Laptop - are in the same Workgroup (I don't use a Domain-Server). The user I am using is the same on the Workstation and the Laptop. Do I need to configure something on my Workstation to manage it's VMs?

Thanks!